# Please explain Date object type conversion

Tags: javascript

I just found a strange behaviour in SpiderMonkey and V8 javascript engines. Suggest finding an explanation would be a good school for everyone

The strange working code:

```
 var x = (new Date()).setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
 typeof x; // "number"
```

The working-as-expected code:

```
var x = new Date(); 
x.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
typeof x; // "object"
x instanceof Date; // true
```

If we find the reason we'll understand how JavaScript works better

Comment: you have typeof in there twice on the third line of the second snippet??

Comment: Pretty sure you have an extra `typeof` there. Try it on the console to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours) setHours sets the date and returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00.

So in the first example, x gets assigned the resulting timestamp which is a number.

To better illustrate, do

```
var y = new Date(),
    x = y.setHours(24,0,0,0)

typeof x // number
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Date.setHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setHours):

> [...] returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC until the time represented by the updated Date instance.

In the first snippet, `x`'s value is a number representing the timestamp, hence its type is `number`.

```
var x = (new Date()).setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
typeof x; // "number"
```

You instance a Date object and call `setHours` on it returning the timestamp which is assigned to `x`.

---

For the second snippet:

```
var x = new Date(); 
x.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0);
typeof x; // "object"
```

`x` is a `Date` object, so this is also expected behavior - take a look at the possible return values of the [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof#Description).

`x` is an instance of `Date`, it inherits the `Date` constructor's prototype hence `x instanceof Date` is `true`.

Comment: OMG, `setHours` changes the object end returns number. This is unexpected as for me

Comment: And I've had a shamely typo

Comment: Offtopic: modern IDEs generate notice for `typeof typeof` so it's a good practice of using IDE, and double testing, of course